# Is there any way to localize marshmallow permissions strings in android?

Tags: android, localization, android-permissions

I am trying to localize the permission messages, like **allow app to access the camera to take photos or videos** etc

Rest of the app is localized.

Here is what i tried so far:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(App.localeManager.setLocale(base));
    Log.d(TAG, "attachBaseContext");
}

public Context setLocale(Context c) {
    return updateResources(c, getLanguage());
}

private Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
   Locale locale = new Locale(language);
   Locale.setDefault(locale);

   Resources res = context.getResources();
   Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

   if (Utility.isAtLeastVersion(JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
    context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

**and one thing if change language in settings, permission messages get localized.**

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Permission requesting dialogs are shown in the locale of the device.